# Using java to upload an image as a blob to an sql database

Tags: java, html, sql

I have a database that is set up like this

```
  CREATE TABLE item (             
              ItemID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
              ItemName char(25),      
              YearManufactured int(11),   
              CopiesSold int(11),
              AmountInStock int(11),
              image blob,                         
              Description char(30),     
              PRIMARY KEY  (`ItemID`)                   
     );
```

The table works fine, and I have been able to insert and delete from it just fine. I want to organize my code a little different and use Java as opposed to writing scriplets to update the table. The initial reason I wanted to switch to do this was because I wanted to be able to upload an image easier. This is my code:

Here is the scriplet to open up initially. The URL, UserID and Password are definitely correct.

```
<%  
    // Instantiating the connection to the database
    String mysJDBCDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    String mysURL = "MY_ADDRESS"; 
    String mysUserID = "USERNAME"; 
    String mysPassword = "PASSWORD";

    java.sql.Connection conn=null; // a new connection
    try 
    {
        DB db = new DB();
        conn=db.dbConnect(mysJDBCDriver, mysURL,mysUserID,mysPassword);
        db.insertImage(conn,"c:/Users/DPiganell/image_launch_a5.jpg");
        db.getImageData(conn);
        System.out.println("Connected successfully to database using JConnect");
        session.setAttribute("connection", conn);

     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.print(e.toString());
    }

%>
```

Here is my DB Object

```
package DBPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class DB
{
        public DB() {}

        public Connection dbConnect(String db_driver, String db_connect_string,
           String db_userid, String db_password)
        {
                try
                {
                        Class.forName(db_driver);
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                          db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

                        System.out.println("connected");
                        return conn;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                }
        }

        public void insertImage(Connection conn,String img)
        {
                int len;
                String query;
                PreparedStatement pstmt;

                try
                {
                        File file = new File(img);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        len = (int)file.length();

//                        query = ("UPDATE item SET image = ? WHERE ItemID = ?");
                        query = ("INSERT INTO ITEM (ItemType, ItemName, YearManufactured, CopiesSold, AmountInStock, image, description) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
                        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                        pstmt.setString(1, "DVD");
                        pstmt.setString(2, "fsd");
                        pstmt.setInt(3, 1991);
                        pstmt.setInt(4, 6);
                        pstmt.setInt(5, 7);
                        pstmt.setString(7, "works");

                        // Method used to insert a stream of bytes
                        pstmt.setBinaryStream(6, (InputStream)fis, len);
                        pstmt.executeUpdate();

                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void getImageData(Connection conn)
        {

                 byte[] fileBytes;
                 String query;
                 try
                 {
                         query = "select image from item where ItemID=3";
                         Statement state = conn.createStatement();
                         ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);
                         if (rs.next())
                        {
                                  fileBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
                                  OutputStream targetFile=  
                                  new FileOutputStream(
                                       "C:/Users/DPiganell/newImage.jpg");

                                  targetFile.write(fileBytes);
                                  targetFile.close();
                        }        

                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                 }
        }
};
```

Once the program reaches executeUpdate, and exception is thrown. Any help is appreciated. I am willing to take a different approach if it is easier.

SQLException Stacktrack:

```
SEVERE: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at DBPackage.DB.insertImage(DB.java:55)
    at org.apache.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:61)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:60)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
SEVERE:     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
SEVERE:     at DBPackage.DB.insertImage(DB.java:55)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:61)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:787)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:60)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: what does the SQLExpection say?

Comment: From the stacktrace you posted your error is in writing a file, not in executing SQL code.

Comment: @Perception In what way? The address is definitely correct.

Comment: The stuff pasted from the exception would be much more useful in its complete form.  From the looks of it, your FileOutputStream is actually the exception thrower, so the SQL stuff is working fine.

Comment: @BaileyS What can I change to provide a better exception for you?

Comment: The first line of an exception tells you what it is, and gives the message.  Subsequent lines start with at, and pretty much trace through what code actually called the exception causing code.  I suppose we need the first line the most, it looks like this `java.io.FileNotFoundException: fred.txt`.  Really, including the whole stack trace in its entirety would be the best.

Comment: @iSelkiies - impossible to say without the complete stacktrace, but these lines `at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:305)
SEVERE:     at DBPackage.DB.getImageData(DB.java:85)` clearly show that your `getImageData` method is called, then `write` is called on FileOutputStream. Two things I would check, 1) that your fileBytes are not null, and 2) The target file doesnt exist already.

Comment: The fileBytes being null would certainly cause an exception not related to SQL, but arising from not successfully reading the blob from the database.

Comment: @Perception I see what you're saying and the fileBytes is null, but the exception is actually thrown inside insertImage and not getImageDate. Once pstmt.executeUpdate is called in insertImage, this is when I get this stacktrace.

Comment: @iSelkiies - can't say what your debugger is showing you, I only have your stacktrace to go by. In any case, you know where to look now for fixing the problem.

Comment: @Perception ah, I see. I've updated the stacktrace. From the previously provided stacktrace, you were correct, but the error that is causing all this is provided in the new updated stacktrace. Mind taking a look?

Comment: The [homework tag has been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). Please don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query syntax looks wrong, Please check the opening and closing brackets.